# access variables from different files in Perl

Tags: perl, file, package

**file1.pl**

```
package ba;
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

our $base_addr = 0x48;
```

**file2.pl**

```
package oa;
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

our $offset_addr = 0;
```

**file3.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

do "file1.pl"
do "file2.pl"

my $final_val;

$final_val = $ba::base_addr + $oa::offset_addr;

printf "base_addr   = 0x%0x\n", $ba::base_addr;
printf "offset_addr = 0x%0x\n",  $oa::offset_addr;
printf "final addr  = 0x%0x\n", $final_val;
```

#### ERRORS###  ->

1. Argument "0x48" isn't numeric.
2. Use of uninitialized value.
3. Use of uninitialized value in addition.

Comment: try `require` instead of `do` http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=760875

Comment: @mpapec: I did try using "require". It is not printing anything from file3.pl and also says file2.pl did not return a true value at file3.pl

Comment: Why are you trying to do this instead of using a configuration file?

Answer (score 4):

Two major errors, both of which are found by using `use strict; use warnings;`. Always do so. (You used it in your modules, but not in your script.)

1. You correctly use `$ba::base_addr` in one spot, but then you proceeded to use non-existent variable `$base_addr` shortly afterwards.

   You can only access `$ba::base_addr` as `$base_addr` if the current package is `ba`, or if you create an alias to it named `$base_addr`.

   You either need to use `$ba::base_addr` consistently, or you need to export the variable to the using module. (This is one way to the alias I mentioned.)
2. You never assign a value to `$ba::base_addr` and `$oa::offset_addr`, so Perl gives you warnings when you attempt to add them ("not numeric") and when you try to print them ("uninitialized").

---

Some other problems we'll fix at the same time:

1. A module must return a true value, which is to say the last expression evaluated must evaluate to something true. It's thus standard to end a module with `1;` (This applies to `do` too for reliable error detection: `do $qfn or die $@ || $!;`.)
2. You should be using `require` instead of `do` since the files have a `package` declaration. It would be even better if you renamed them to `.pm` and used `use`.
3. The name of a module should match it's package declaration. If it contains `package ba;`, the file should be named `ba.pm`.
4. `#!` is only meaningful if 1) they are the first two characters of the file, and 2) if the file is provided to the OS for execution. Neither of those are the case for your modules.

---

`ba.pm`:

```
package ba;

use strict;
use warnings;

our $base_addr = 123;

1;
```

`oa.pm`:

```
package oa;

use strict;
use warnings;

our $offset_addr = 456;

1;
```

`script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use ba qw( );
use oa qw( );

my $final_val = $ba::base_addr + $oa::offset_addr;

print "base_addr   = $ba::base_addr\n";
print "offset_addr = $oa::offset_addr\n";
print "final addr  = $final_val\n";
```

---

You could avoid saying the package name everywhere if you exported the variables, and mentioned earlier.

`ba.pm`:

```
package ba;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw( import );
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( $base_addr );

our $base_addr = 123;

1;
```

`oa.pm`:

```
package oa;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw( import );
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( $offset_addr );

our $offset_addr = 456;

1;
```

`script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use ba qw( $base_addr );
use oa qw( $offset_addr );

my $final_val = $base_addr + $offset_addr;

print "base_addr   = $base_addr\n";
print "offset_addr = $offset_addr\n";
print "final addr  = $final_val\n";
```

---

It's typically bad form to export variables, though. It's usually far better to create accessors.

`ba.pm`:

```
package ba;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw( import );
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( base_addr );

my $base_addr = 123;

sub base_addr { $base_addr }

1;
```

`oa.pm`:

```
package oa;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw( import );
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( offset_addr );

my $offset_addr = 456;

sub base_addr { $base_addr }

1;
```

`script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use ba qw( base_addr );
use oa qw( offset_addr );

my $final_val = base_addr() + offset_addr();

print "base_addr   = ".base_addr()."\n";
print "offset_addr = ".offset_addr()."\n";
print "final addr  = $final_val\n";
```

Comment: Also he has a syntax error: our offset_addr; - not using $ before the variable name and not returning true at the end of the module.

Comment: @user4035, I know. Theses problems are fixed by the code I posted.

Comment: @ikegami: I implemented things as you have told. But still getting the above errors.

Comment: Which of the three sets of snippets did you run?

Comment: @ikegami: file3.pl
....
My base_addr and offset_addr are defined as 0x48 and 4 respectively.. Is that causing a problem?

Comment: @ikegami: 

(1) Argument "0x48" isn't numeric in printf at file3.pl line 14.
base_addr   = 0x0


(2) Use of uninitialized value in printf at file3.pl line 15.
offset_addr = 0x0


(3) Use of uninitialized value in addition (+) at file3.pl line 17.
final addr = 0x0

Comment: The first error is that you did `'0x48'` (a four character string) instead of `0x48` (the number seventy-two). There's no `printf` anywhere in the code you mentioned. Please provide a minimal runnable demonstration of the problem...

Comment: No thanks. If you have a new question to ask, chat's not the place to ask.

Comment: @ikegami: I do have printf statements in my code, because I am printing a value. I forgot to type it in my question.
Also, in the errors that it throws, it puts 0x48 in quotes. I have just defined 0x48 in my perl module

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename your files, add return values and include them using `use`. Here:

file1.p**m**

```
package ba;

use strict;
use warnings;

our $base_addr = 17;

1;
```

file2.p**m**

```
package oa;

use strict;
use warnings;

our $offset_addr = 19;

1;
```

file3.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use file1;
use file2;

my $final_val;

$final_val = $ba::base_addr + $oa::offset_addr;

print "base_addr = $ba::base_addr\n";
print "offset_addr = $oa::offset_addr\n";
print "final addr = $final_val\n";
```

Comment: (package and file name should match, so you only half-fixed the file names)

Comment: It's a good practice, yes, but they don't have to be the same. It's up to OP to decide; I'm merely answering his question.

Comment: Then use `use file1 ();` cause you're currently executing `file1::import()`. (In short, yeah, they really do need to be the same.)